# AWK with multiple delimiters

Tags: mysql, awk, sed, tshark

I'm trying to insert tshark output to MySQL database. Tshark output has a format:

```
VALUE1:VALUE2_1|VALUE2_2|VALUE2_3:VALUE3_1,VALUE3_2,VALUE3_3:VALUE4:VALUE5
```

Currently I'm trying to redirect the output through the pipe to sed and awk:

```
|sed -u "s/^/insert into data (item1, item2, item3, item4, item5) values('/g"|awk -F":" -v OFS=',' '{print $1,$2}'
```

, but only some values are necessary.

So that the resulting command must look like:

```
insert into data (item1, item2, item3, item4, item5) values(value1,value2_2,value3_2,value4,value5)
```

And some example from  development environment:

Tshark permanently generates these kind of output:

```
1418043291.268345000:14567744356|4|8v95489464:DC0289001840,NNN100,DC206286661:03612037:ON1774B01
1418043291.201703000:14567744356|0|6b10992051:DC0289001840,NNN120,DC081276320:04891241:ON891N619
```

, where

1. 1418043291.268345000 - VALUE1
2. 14567744356|4|8v95489464 - VALUE2
3. DC0289001840,NNN100,DC206286661 - VALUE3
4. 03612037 - VALUE4
5. ON1774B01 - VALUE5

For VALUE2 and VALUE3 is interested only the middle row, i.e "4" for VALUE2 and "NN100" for VALUE3. All of the other rows from these values (VALUE2, VALUE3) are not necessary for the further calculations from out side, that's why they must be discarded and the resulting insert command must looks like:

```
insert into data (item1, item2, item3, item4, item5) values(1418043291.268345000,4,NNN100,03612037,ON1774B01)
```

Could you please advise, how to modify the awk command for inserting values:

```
 VALUE1:VALUE2_2:VALUE3_2:VALUE4:VALUE5 ?
```

Comment: it is clear what you want but a bit unclear how you get there: what is the general rule to know which fields need to be chosen and which ones should be dropped?

Comment: wich criteria is given the "good" value to take ? why value 2_1, value2_3 and value3_3 are discarded (each with different pre or post kind of separator but the  same as one of the other that is taken) ? Is is just the arbitrary place order ?

Comment: fedorqui, NeronLeVelu, thanks for response!
I have added some more detailed explanations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your sample, explaination and with few simplification and no awk (not needed in this case and heavier for OS)

```
sed 's/\([^:]*\):[^|]*|\([^|]*\)|[^,]*,\([^,]*\),[^:]*:\([^:]*\):\(.*\)/insert into data (item1, item2, item3, item4, item5) values(\1,\2,\3,\4,\5)/' YourFile
```

(posix version so `--posix`on GNU sed)

the real full structure is using full value and sub group:

```
sed 's/\([^:]*\):\([^|]*|\([^|]*\)|^[^:]*\):\([^,]*,\([^,]*\),[^:]*\):\([^:]*\):\(.*\)/insert into data (item1, item2, item3, item4, item5) values(\1,\3,\5,\6,\7)/' YourFile
```

now, a awk only is also possible, sed followed by awk is to avoid (often possible) for a performance and ressource point of view

Comment: And one more question: if I'm trying to add additional values (by adding regex \([^:]*\)):

1. till the 9 values - everything is ok
2. >9 value - problem is occurring. \10,\11..\19 value prints the \1 value. 

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: yes, sed have a limitation to 9 group. You need to do it in several s/// or use shortcut if possible to limit the group to max 9